# Javascript nested object deep search

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function, which search for an existing key in a nested object, and reports the value.

The problem is, if `input ='d'`, I get `undefined` and I expect `'test-d'`. 
It looks like I miss a return when it's not found

My code

```js
var foo = {
  a: 'test-a',
  b: {
    myProp: 'test-prop',
    foo: {
      last: 'test-last'
    }
  },
  c: {
    d: 'test-d'
  }
};


var search = function(input, objs) {
  for (key in objs) {
    //   console.log(key+ '---'+ input);
    if (typeof objs[key] == 'object') {
      return search(input, objs[key]);
    } else {
      if (input == key) {
        return result = objs[input];
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(search("d",foo))
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning early, problem in the `if(typeof objs[key] =='object'){
         return search(input, objs[key]);
    }`, it does not get to c at all

Comment: Undefined, because your function never go to object 'c'. It's ending on foo['last']

Comment: oh, got it, I switch it to `var result = search(input, objs[key]);
      if(result){
         return result;
       }else{
        continue;
       }` and it worked.